# Change a string to date with particular format?

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

I have a string like "2016-04-13". I need to change it to a date format like
"13 April, 2016". How can I do this in JavaScript?

What I've tried:

```
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

Comment: try this http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `String.replace` function and predefined *month names* list:

```
var dt = new Date("2016-04-13".replace("-","/")),
    monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var dateStr = dt.getDate() +" "+ monthNames[dt.getMonth()] +", "+ dt.getFullYear();
console.log(dateStr);  // 13 April, 2016
```

Comment: @SumitAggarwal, what `NaN`? The above code works fine.

Comment: its give me NaN while console the data

Comment: check you code for errors. At least, you can copy/paste the above working code

Comment: i exactly copy paste the above code its give me same answers NaN undefined, NaN

Comment: the above code outputs: `13 April, 2016`. Make sure that there's no conflicting/overriding variable names in your code

Comment: i paste in the end of the document under script tag still same